# How to trigger environment reload using C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, environment

I am trying to write a custom installer for my application. I am making this installer using C#. One of the features of this is adding my app's directory to PATH.

However, when I do this, I have to reboot my computer to be able to access the updated PATH variable. When using a setup scripting tool like Inno setup, I can set it to somehow reload the environment to access the updated PATH immediately without having to reboot. How can I replicate this behaviour using C#?

I am sorry if this is a duplicate question but I am unable to find anything on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was trying to modify the registry. You can access it immediately by using `System.Environment`

```
var name = "PATH";
var scope = EnvironmentVariableTarget.User; // or User
var oldValue = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, scope);
var newValue = oldValue + @";C:\Path\To\Add";
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the PATH variable in Windows should not require a reboot. A simple solution is to add the directory containing your executable and any folder it uses to your PATH variable. For example:

System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86).ToString() + ""
ather for Program Files (x86) on " + System.Environment.OSVersion.Name

Comment: I was doing it all incorrectly and trying to use it by changing the registry value. Now SO won't let me close this question